# undefined method __path rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a form for submitting feedback. I defined the resources properly under a namespace. But still I am getting the following error.

```
 undefined method `feedbacks_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000009d3def8>:0x00000009d5fb20>
```

Given below is the code I am using

feedbacks_controller.rb

```
class AdminConsoles::FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin_console'
  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    unless @feedback.save
        redirect_to(:back)
    else
        redirect_to admin_console_feedback_path(@feedback)
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  private

  def feedback_params
    params[:feedback].permit(:name,:email,:phone,:message)
  end
```

end

form html page

```
<div class='row'>
<%= form_for @feedback do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Name (optional)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'eg:pavan'%>
    <%= f.label "Email (optional)" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'eg:xyz@gmail.com' %>
    <%= f.label "Phone (optional)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone,placeholder: 'eg:+91943343334'%>
    <%= f.label :Message %>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'input span2 btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin_consoles, path: 'admin' do
    resources :bulk_emails, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show]
    resources :feedbacks, only: [:new, :show, :create]
    resources :vendor_accounts
    resources :vendor_profiles do
      put :enable, as: :enable, on: :member
      put :disable, as: :disable, on: :member
      put :publish, as: :publish, on: :member
      put :modify_services, as: :modify_services, on: :member
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= form_for [:admin_consoles, @feedback] do |f| %>
```